# Using For to create struct to initialize

Tags: c, list, hashtable

Hi I have a problem I'm trying to initialize an hashtable with an array that contains list but when I'm using a **for** loop, all the data are "shared". I've to initialize mannualy like that :

```
   struct objec_listt A,B; // Initialization of 2 two structure A and B
   INIT_LIST_HEAD(&A.list); // A is headlist
   INIT_LIST_HEAD(&B.list); // B is headlist
   hashtable->tab[0]= &A; // I insert A into the array
   hashtable->tab[1]= &B; // I insert B into the array

   insert(1,tab[0]); //  insert 1, not real syntax 
   insert(2,tab[0]); //  insert 2
   insert(3,tab[1]); //  insert 3
```

Now I print tab[0] and tab[1] with my own function and I get

tab[0] = 1,2

tab[2]= 3

Ok it works as I want

**If I do like that It doesnt work :**

```
   for(i=0; i<2; i++)
   {
     struct objec_listt A;
     INIT_LIST_HEAD(&A.list);
     hashtable->tab[i] = &A
   }

   insert(1,tab[0]); //  insert 1,
   insert(2,tab[0]); //  insert 2
   insert(3,tab[1]); //  insert 3
```

If I do a 
printf :

tab[0] : 1,2,3

tab[1] : 1,2,3

So the problem is like I'm trying to create "many object" that will be head of list, and for each 
I need to initialize an array with a size of 100, so that why I'm looking to do with loop

Thanks !

Comment: didn't you forget the "&" in the INIT_LIST_HEAD statement inside the for clause?

Comment: You have run into a `scope` issue, you must move `struct objec_listt A;` outside of the for loop. Since it is created within the loop, once you exit that code block it no longer exists. The declaration was local to the for loop block of code.

Comment: Well I already tried outside of the loop but it doesnt work :(

Comment: Did you try something similar to what I posted below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comment, in other words, you would need something similar to the following to avoid the declaration within the `for` loop code block:

```
struct objec_listt A[2];

for(i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&A[i].list);
    hashtable->tab[i] = &A[i];
}

insert(1,tab[0]); //  insert 1,
insert(2,tab[0]); //  insert 2
insert(3,tab[1]); //  insert 3
```

In your example, when you declare `struct objec_listt A` within the for loop block, `A` has a lifetime only within the block between the `{}`. When the for loop exits, the memory of `A` is marked as released and can then be use again by your program for anything it needs -- that's not what you want. By moving the declaration outside of the for loop, you insure that `A` continues to exist *in scope* until you exit the block that contains `A`.

Comment: Glad I could help. I've been bitten by that a time or two `:)`